# Keep duplicate entries from two JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have two JSON objects in a Lambda function (python). I want to compare the  keys from object 2 against the keys in object 1 and remove any entries that are not contained in object 1.

Each object has a few hundred items in it, so a nested for loop will take too long and time out. I found diffpy, but this requires a module imported into my lambda and I would like to, ideally have a native python solution (to minimize the size of my lambda function).

```
object1 = [{'name': 'apple', 'price': 100}, {'name': 'grape', 'price': 
150}, {'name': 'orange', 'price': 40}]

object2 = [{'name': 'apple', 'price': 200}, {'name': 'grape', 'price': 
350}, {'name': 'orange', 'price': 40}, {'name': 'mango', 'price': 400}]
```

In the example above, the expected newObject should have only the name key/value from the first object and the price key/values from both objects. Mango from object 2 is not contained in object 1 so we can disregard.

```
newObject = [{'name': 'apple', 'priceA': 100, 'priceB': 200}, {'name': 
'grape', 'priceA': 150, 'priceB': 350}, {'name': 'orange', 'priceA': 40, 
'priceB': 40}]
```

I have attempted to use the following code to implement:

```
newHash= {}
newObject = []
for item in object1:
    name = item["name"]
    priceA = item["price"]
    for item in object2:
        if name == item["name"]:
            newHash["name"] = item["name"]
            newHash["priceA"] = priceA
            newHash["priceB"] = item["price"]
            newObject.append(newHash)
```

Comment: Turn the two lists into sets, then use the `intersection` function.

Comment: @DeepSpace, for some reason, I found this time around, my code was running much faster (300x400 only around 100k iterations) after I implemented a nested for loop so not sure why it was hung up (a few minutes) last time. If the same name exists with a different price, the two prices will be combined into one object (I only posed the question this way for brevity sake). 

Thanks!

Comment: give me a moment

Comment: So sorry, yeah I can see it was a bit confusing. I updated the question hopefully it's a bit more clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you modify the structure of your objects the code you showed is as "optimized" as you can probably get, due to the fact you are using a list of dictionaries there is no way to remove the nested loops that will iterate through each list to find the correct dictionary.

Consider using the names as keys in `object1` and `object2`, ie `{'apple': 100, 'grape': 150}`. This way you will have direct access in order to find the common keys. The structure of the output can stay as you wish.

```
object1 = {'apple': 100,
           'grape': 150,
           'orange': 40}

object2 = {'apple': 200,
           'grape': 350,
           'orange': 40,
           'mango': 400}

common_keys = object1.keys() & object2.keys()

output = [{'name': key, 'priceA': object1[key], 'priceB': object2[key]}
          for key in common_keys]
print(output)
#  [{'name': 'apple', 'priceA': 100, 'priceB': 200},
#   {'name': 'grape', 'priceA': 150, 'priceB': 350},
#   {'name': 'orange', 'priceA': 40, 'priceB': 40}]
```

Comment: This definitely put me in the right direction. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Well, as has already been suggested in the comments, the problem is a little incomplete, as we don't know what you want to do if the same name exists in both sets with a different price.

As also noted in the comments, you can use a set object and its .intersection () method to get what you want.

```
lambda o1,o2: [x for x in o1 if x['name'] in set(y['name'] for y in o1). intersection (set(z['name'] for z in o2))]
```

That ought to work, on the assumption that the first argument to the lambda takes precedence. You can change the "x for x in o1" to "x for x in o2" to make the second version take precedence.

If you want to exclude things with different prices but the same name, things get a little more complicated. I don't know what your use case is or why the objects are structured as they are, but it might be easier if you did this:

```
po1={x['name']:x['price'] for x in object1}
po2={x['name']:x['price'] for x in object2}
[{'name':x,'price':po1[x]} for x in set(po1).intersection (set(po2)) if po1[x]==po2[x]]
```

Obviously that's not a lambda or a one-liner but it's a little more flexible (get rid of the if part to make object1 take precedence instead of excluding conflicting values, for example).